# Red wire 12V or 5V... How to tell?

Tags: voltage, ground, fan

This is my first post on Electrical engineering, so bear with me.

I'm making a project for school that is supposed to mimic a wind turbine. So, it will use a case fan for a computer as the "turbine". When looking at diagrams on Google, I see that there are usually only 4 wires:

- yellow (tachometer)
- black (ground)
- black (ground)
- red (12V or 5V).

Some diagrams literally say *12V or 5V*.

My question is: how do I tell what the red wires voltage is? I would prefer 5V.

Thanks in advance! I can provide more info if needed.

Edit: like this: https://youtu.be/jiAhiu6UqXQ

Comment: What does the label on the fan say? Do you have a datasheet for it?

Comment: https://www.google.ca/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=computer+case+fan+voltage

Comment: The video you've linked is a hoax. Ignore it.

Comment: @duskwuff Darn... I was so hopeful. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Having assisted a number of "model wind turbine projects" one thing that is instantly clear is that there is VERY little power in a small swept area (blade disk) at any normal wind speed; and the mechanics of larger swept area tend to exceed the tooling and budget of fun projects rather quickly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm making a project for school that is supposed to mimic a wind turbine. So, it will use a case fan for a computer as the "turbine".

If you mean that you intend to blow air at the case fan and use it as a generator, I have bad news: that won't work.

Most modern computer fans use a [brushless DC motor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushless_DC_electric_motor) design. These motors cannot be "back-powered" to run as a generator, as they depend on electronic controls to drive the stator coils.

If you plan to simply run the fan, though, standard computer case fans are all designed to run on 12V. They may run slowly on a 5V input, though.

Comment: What if I were to use a brushed motor and use another means of propulsion?

Comment: http://www.robotshop.com/ca/en/solarbotics-regular-motor-2.html would this work?

Comment: No way to tell without a real datasheet -- and even then, it's probably not specified. Buy it and find out, I guess, but don't expect much power, especially unless you can run it near its operating speed (7K RPM).